# getting mean of value in matrix changes matrix

Tags: python, matrix, pandas

I am getting mean of ambiguate elements in  matrix

```
    import pandas as pd
    ds2 = [[ 4,  1],
           [ 5,  3],
           [ 6,  1],
           [ 7,  2],
           [ 7,  2],
           [ 8,  2],
           [12,  1],
           [ 9,  3],
           [12,  1],
           [13,  2],
           [22,  3]]
    ds2= pd.DataFrame(ds2)
    print type(ds2)
    print ds2
    ds2 = ds2.groupby(0).mean()
    print type(ds2)
    print ds2
```

output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    0  1
0   4  1
1   5  3
2   6  1
3   7  2
4   8  2
5   9  3
6  12  1
7  13  2
8  22  3
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    1
0    
4   1
5   3
6   1
7   2
8   2
9   3
12  1
13  2
22  3
```

Type remains same, but the way matrix looks change, is there any way to persist matrix view even after processing?

Comment: Is `ds2.groupby(0, as_index=False).mean()` what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Pass param `as_index=False` to the [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) method:

```
In [140]:

ds2 = [[ 4,  1],
           [ 5,  3],
           [ 6,  1],
           [ 7,  2],
           [ 7,  2],
           [ 8,  2],
           [12,  1],
           [ 9,  3],
           [12,  1],
           [13,  2],
           [22,  3]]
ds2= pd.DataFrame(ds2)
ds2.groupby(0, as_index=False).mean()
Out[140]:
    0  1
0   4  1
1   5  3
2   6  1
3   7  2
4   8  2
5   9  3
6  12  1
7  13  2
8  22  3
```

By default any columns passed will be used to form the index.

From the docs:

```
as_index : boolean, default True
For aggregated output, return object
with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input.
as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output
```